# Show that if $X\sim\text{Pois}(\theta)$, then $I(\theta;X) = 1/\theta$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

The Fisher information matrix $I(\theta;X)$ about $\theta$ based on $X$ is defined as the matrix with elements $$I_{i,j}(\theta;X) = \operatorname{Cov}_\theta\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i}\log f_X(X\mid\theta), \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log f_X(X\mid \theta) \bigg).$$

**Exercise:** Let $X\sim \text{Pois}(\theta)$. Show that $I(\theta;X) = 1/\theta$.

*What I've tried:* If I'm not mistaken then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} \log f_X(X \mid \theta) = \dfrac{x_i}{\theta} + \log e$. The Fisher information matrix (a $1\times 1$ matrix in this example) would be given by $\operatorname{Cov}_\theta\left(\dfrac{x_i} \theta + \log e, \dfrac{x_i} \theta + \log e\right)$. We know that $\operatorname{Cov}_\theta\left(\dfrac{x_i} \theta + \log e, \dfrac{x_i}{\theta} + \log e\right) = \operatorname{Var}_\theta\left(\dfrac{x_i}\theta + \log e\right) = \operatorname{Var}_\theta \left(\dfrac{x_i}{\theta}\right) = x_i^2 \operatorname{Var}_\theta \left(\dfrac 1 \theta \right).$ Obviously I'm doing something wrong as the $x_i^2$ before the variance is a problem. Besides that, I'm not sure if I can calculate $\operatorname{Var}_\theta\left(\dfrac 1 
 \theta \right)$.

**Question:** How do I show that $I(\theta;X) = 1/\theta$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\operatorname{Var}_\theta \left(\dfrac{x_i}{\theta}\right) = x_i^2 \operatorname{Var}_\theta \left(\dfrac 1 \theta \right)$ doesn't make sense. You need $\operatorname{Var}_\theta \left(\dfrac{x_i}{\theta}\right) = \dfrac 1 {\theta^2} \operatorname{Var}_\theta (x_i). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why is that so? It's the variance w.r.t. $\theta$ right? Don't we use $\text{Var}_X$ so show that the variance is to be taken w.r.t. $X$?

Comment: $\theta$ is a parameter and so it is just a constant. The notation $E_\theta$ or $\operatorname{Var}_\theta$ just lists the relevant parameter(s) in the subscript. The random quantities are still $X$ and all things derived from it.

Comment: @KimJongUn What would relevant mean in this sense? I'd say it's rather confusing. When taking the expectation $\operatorname{E}_X$ we mean that we take the expectation wrt $X$ right?

Comment: @titusAdam : No. I don't take expected values or variances "with respect to" anything. Rather $\operatorname{Var}_\theta$ means the variance given that the value of the parameter is $\theta. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well it's clear now, so thank you! I do find this part of the notation quite clumsy though. It doesn't seem to be uncommon to take expected values or variances "with respect to" something: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72613/subscript-notation-in-expectations

Comment: @titusAdam : I see that from time to time and I've seen it in Wikipedia articles, but it's a mistake. One _could_ speak of expected values or variances "with respect to" particular probability distributions, but that's another matter: $\displaystyle \operatorname E(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\, P(d\omega). \qquad$

Comment: @titusAdam : Notice what the _answer_ says, to the question you linked to.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in the last step:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(x_i/\theta) {{}\color{red}={}} x_i^2\operatorname{Var}(1/\theta).
$$
**Instead**, it should be
$$
\operatorname{Var}(x_i/\theta)=\operatorname{Var}(x_i)/\theta^2=\theta/\theta^2=1/\theta.
$$

Comment: When you used \text{Var} instead of \operatorname{Var} then you don't get proper spacing in things like $3\operatorname{Var}(X)$ or $3\operatorname{Var} X.$ Instead you see $3\text{Var}(X)$ or $3\text{Var} X.$ I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks Mike. Glad to learn something new.